# Maxlength property of input field is not respected

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have the following React method which should create an input field with a maximum length:

```
displayInputField: function(name, placeholder, updateMethod, maxLength) {
        return (
            <div className="form-group form-inline">
                <label>{name}</label>
                <input onChange={updateMethod} type="text" className="form-control"
                     maxlength={maxLength} placeholder={placeholder}/>

            </div>
        );
    },
```

However, the input field generated does not stop me from inputting more characters.
Its source is this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="<15 characters" data-reactid=".0.1.2.0.0.1.2.1.0.1">
```

Why is the maxlength attribute not respected?

Comment: Should it be `maxLength`? (Note the capital L!)

Comment: `maxLength` argument is not a null?

Comment: @TwoStraws, It should not be that strict. The HTML5 standard does not require lowercase attribute names.

Comment: He's not using HTML, he's using JSX.

Comment: Won't it be rendered as HTML ? Just a doubt!

Comment: It becomes JavaScript that ultimately leads to HTML, yes, but as you can see the output HTML has no maximum length attribute at all – either `maxLength` or `maxlength` :)

Comment: @TwoStraws. Thanks a lot. I didn't realize that it will be case sensitive because of JSX. Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: @octavian See the link in my answer. I'm glad it's fixed!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your problem here was that you had written `maxlength` when in JSX it should have been `maxLength`. This lower camel case approach is the same for all HTML attributes, e.g. `cellPadding`, `encType`, and so on.

Remember, your JSX ultimately is JavaScript; you should read the [list of supported tags and attributes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html) if you're not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Just try below implementing in your input field

```
onInput={(e) => {e.target.value = Math.max( 0,    parseInt(e.target.value)).toString().slice(0, 4);}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<input className="form-control" maxLength={30} size={30} name="subject" />
```